# ¿Porque axios desde mi componente categoria.vue no envia peticiones al controlador desde /routes/web.php?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

¡Buenos noches!; les saluda el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo, tengo un problema en mi proyecto Laravel ya que desde mi componente vue (categoria.vue) que esta en la ruta de mi proyecto (/resources/js/components/categoria.vue) uso axios para realizar las peticiones al controlador, adjunto el siguiente código de "categoria.vue"

```html
<template>
   <main class="main">
            <!-- Breadcrumb -->
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active"><a href="/">BACKEND - SISTEMA DE COMPRAS - VENTAS</a></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">

                       <h2>Listado de Categorías</h2><br/>
                      
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" @click="abrirModal('categoria','registrar')">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-2x"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Agregar Categoría
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <select class="form-control col-md-3">
                                      <option value="nombre">Categoría</option>
                                      <option value="descripcion">Descripción</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar texto">
                                    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm">
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="bg-primary">
                                   
                                    <th>Categoría</th>
                                    <th>Descripción</th>
                                    <th>Estado</th>
                                    <th>Editar</th>
                                    <th>Cambiar Estado</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                               
                                <tr v-for="categoria in arrayCategoria" :key="categoria.id">
                                    
                                    <td v-text="categoria.nombre"></td>
                                    <td v-text="categoria.descripcion"></td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md" v-if="categoria.condicion">
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Activo
                                        </button>

                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" v-else>
                                    
                                          <i class="fa fa-check fa-2x"></i> Desactivado
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>

                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-md" @click="abrirModal('categoria','actualizar',categoria)">

                                          <i class="fa fa-edit fa-2x"></i> Editar
                                        </button> &nbsp;
                                    </td>

                                    <td>

                                        
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            <i class="fa fa-lock fa-2x"></i> Desactivar
                                        </button>
                                       
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                               
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <nav>
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Anterior</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item active">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">4</a>
                                </li>
                               
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a class="page-link" href="#">Siguiente</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Fin ejemplo de tabla Listado -->
            </div>
            <!--Inicio del modal agregar/actualizar-->
            <div class="modal fade" :class="{'mostrar':modal}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary modal-lg" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title" v-text="tituloModal"></h4>
                            <button type="button" @click="cerrarModal()" class="close" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            
                            <div class="form-group row div-error">
                                
                                <div class="text-center text-error">
                                    
                                    <div></div>

                                </div>
                            
                            </div>
                             

                            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="text-input">Categoría</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="text" v-model="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre de categoría">
                                       
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 form-control-label" for="email-input">Descripción</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input type="email" v-model="descripcion" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese descripcion">
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" @click="cerrarModal()" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-times fa-2x"></i> Cerrar</button>
                            <button type="button" @click="registrarCategoria()" v-if="tipoAccion==1" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Guardar</button>
                            <button type="button" v-if="tipoAccion==2" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-save fa-2x"></i> Actualizar</button>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div>
            <!--Fin del modal-->
           
        
        </main>
</template>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<script>
   
    export default {
        data(){

            return {

                nombre:'',
                descripcion:'',
                arrayCategoria:[],
                modal:0,
                tituloModal:'',
                tipoAccion:0
            }

        },

        methods:{

           listarCategoria(){

               let me=this;

               const axios = require('axios');

               axios.get('/categoria').then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    //console.log(response);
                    me.arrayCategoria=response.data;
                   
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                });
           },

           registrarCategoria(){

               let me=this;

               const axios = require('axios');

               axios.post('/categoria/registrar',{

                   nombre:this.nombre,
                   descripcion:this.descripcion

                   //'nombre':this.nombre,
                   //'descripcion':this.descripcion 
               }).then(function (response){
                   //handle success
                   //console.log(response);
                   me.cerrarModal();
                   me.listarCategoria();


               })
               .catch(function (error){
                   // handle error
                   console.log(error);

               }) 
           },

           cerrarModal(){

               this.modal=0;
               this.tituloModal="";
               this.nombre="";
               this.descripcion="";

           },

           abrirModal(modelo,accion,data=[]){
                 
                 switch(modelo){

                    case "categoria":
                    
                    {

                        switch(accion){

                            case "registrar":

                                {
                                   
                                   this.modal=1;
                                   this.tituloModal="Registrar Categoria";
                                   this.nombre="";
                                   this.descripcion="";
                                   this.tipoAccion=1;
                                
                                }

                                case "actualizar":

                                {

                                
                                }
                        
                        }


                    }

                }

                        
           }
        
        },
        
        mounted() {
            //console.log('Component mounted.')
            this.listarCategoria();
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
        
     .modal-content{

      width:100% !important;
      position:absolute !important;
  }

  .mostrar{

      display:list-item !important;
      opacity:1 !important;
      position:absolute !important;
      background-color:#3c29297a !important;
  }

</style>
```

La idea es que desde Axios realice peticiones a mi controlador para extraer registros desde la base de datos, que el archivo (/routes/web.php) de mi proyecto Laravel recive estas peticiones y llama al controlador (en este caso envía como petición categoría e invoca al controlador "CategoriaController.php" (que esta en la carpeta /app/HTTp/Controllers/CategoriaController.php) de mi proyecto Laravel, adjunto el código del archivo "web.php" (que esta en la carpeta /routes).

```html
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('contenido/contenido');
});

Route::get('/categoria', 'CategoriaController@index');
Route::post('/categoria/registrar', 'CategoriaController@store');
Route::put('/categoria/actualizar', 'CategoriaController@update');
Route::put('/categoria/desactivar', 'CategoriaController@desactivar');
Route::put('/categoria/activar', 'CategoriaController@activar');
```

Ahora bien el archivo "CategoriaController.php" que esta en la ruta (/app/HTTp/Controller/CategoriaController.php) que extrae la información pero de acuerdo a lo que indicó con la función index:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Resources\CategoriaResource;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Categoria;

class CategoriaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
        $categorias= Categoria::all();
        return $categorias;
       
    }

    

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= new Categoria();
        $categoria->nombre= $request->nombre;
        $categoria->descripcion= $request->descripcion;
        $categoria->condicion= '1';
        $categoria->save();
    }


    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= Categoria::findOrFail($request->id);
        $categoria->nombre= $request->nombre;
        $categoria->descripcion= $request->descripcion;
        $categoria->condicion= '1';
        $categoria->save();
    }

    public function desactivar(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= Categoria::findOrFail($request->id);
        $categoria->condicion= '0';
        $categoria->save();
    }

    public function activar(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $categoria= Categoria::findOrFail($request->id);
        $categoria->condicion= '1';
        $categoria->save();
    }

    
}
```

También incluí un archivo de recursos que lo llame CategoriaResource con el siguiente código:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class CategoriaResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        //return parent::toArray($request);
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'nombre' => $this->nombre,
            'descripcion' => $this->descripcion,
            'condicion' => $this->condicion
        ];
    }
}
```

Lo que me sale en la pantalla lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto unos links sobre documentación de Axios que habla como usar Axios:

[Como usar Axios](https://styde.net/solicitudes-http-con-axios/)

[Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿en el archivo app.js del proyecto laravel que esta en la carpeta /resources/app.js hay que incluir alguna librería para poder utilizar axios o algo por el estilo ya que no realiza peticiones como dije antes desde Axios al controlador desde el archivo (/routes/web.php); adjunto código del archivo tambien (/resources/app.js)

```html
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
// files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key)))


Vue.component('categoria', require('./components/Categoria.vue'));

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data:{
        
        menu:0
    },
});
```

Estimados amigos de comunidad de programnadores de stackoverFlow este es el error que me sale al ejecutar mi proyecto laravel que adjunto print de pantalla para ver la manera de como solucionarlo, si tiene sugerencias que quieran hacermo a la solución de este problema se los agradezco, y adjunto print de pantalla.

Lo que se pide es que las peticiones que se realiza por axios desde mi componente vue categoeia.vue pasen al cintrolador CategoriaController.php por medio del archivo /routes/web.php que es donde toma la petición y envia al controlador antes mencionado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: instalaste axios en vue?

Comment: @gbianchi Estimado en vue antes de usar axios puse cons axios = require('axios'); ya que ya hay dependencia de axios que lo verifique en el archivo package.json que hace referencia a Axios en este archivo, ahora ¿no lo se a que te refieres si instale axios en vue?, ¿te refieres acaso de un script que llame a una pagina web sobre la libreria axios.min.js?

Comment: @gbianchi revisa este link por el uso de axios https://github.com/axios/axios que hice como este el ejemplo y antes en mi componente vue para usar axios puse cons axios = require('axios'); como vas a encontrar un ejemplo en la página web que te indique, ahora bien no lo se si se debe de incluir un script que haga referencia a una página web donde esta la libreria de axios.min.js, ya que revisando las dependencias en el archivo de mi proyecto laravel package.json hace referencia a axios estimado

Comment: Jose, yo se usar axios en vue. Esta pregunta me suena muy similar a la que ya hiciste anteriormente. Cual es el problema concreto que tenes? ya te preguntamos muchas veces si la ruta que le mandas a axios es la correcta. Cual es el problema concreto? Tu componente solo debe hacer un include de axios. Hay montones de ejemplos en google de como hacer eso.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi la idea de Axios es enviar petición via HTTp en este caso categoria al controlador que lo recive la peticion el archivo /routes/web.php con la petición indicada y llama al controlador CategoriaController.php a la función index como te especifique en mi código de /routes/web.php en el código que adjunte con la pregunta.

Comment: @gbianchi en otro ocación me dijiste que via en network la ruta que apunta al controlador pero digo al archivo web.php se me ocurre esto y no lo se si funcione que lo pongo cons axios = require('axios'); y axios.get('http://localhost:4500/categoria) eso es lo que se me acurre vea el puerto que apunta el archivo no lo se si estoy en lo cierto que supongamos de ese puerto no lo se si puedes darme una ayuda al respecto.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi estimado amigo te saluda el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo de lo que te dije que verifique el puerto que apunta el archivo puede que lo obtenga al ejecutar el proyecto laravel de un click con el boton derecho en inspeccionar y de las opciones que sale escoger network (redes) para ver el puerto que apunto mi archivo /routes/web.php t supongamos que sea el puerto 5400 por ejemplo y desde mi compinente vue categoria.vue que esta en la ruta /resources/js/components/categoria.vue en el script en axio poner axio.get('http://localhost:5400/categoria') esto esto lo que creo

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi buenos días!; te saluda el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo desde Ecuador para resolver el problema que te estaba comentando de las peticiones de url mediante axios en mi componente vue no lo se si puede funcionar es axios.get('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/routes/web.php?categoria') que es la ruta en este caso de mi proyecto al archivo que quiero enviar la petición en este caso categoría ya que revise en network aunque no verifique el puerto pero esta es la ruta del archivo que quiero pasar el parámetro categoria, no lo se si de esta manera, te pido me contestes.

Comment: O sea, tu pregunta es que url pasarle a axios para lograr llegar a tu controler?

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi así es estimado axios envia la petición http a traves de un url que en el archivo /routes/web.php lo que hace a traves de la petición envia al controlador CategoriaController@index que ejecuta la función index del controlador para extraer los resultados de la tabla de la base de datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95031/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-jose-fernando-frugone-jaramill).

Comment: Estimada @Nubia Katiuska ¡Buenas noches!; te saluda el Lcdo. José Fernando Frugone Jaramillo desde Ecuador. te escribo para que me ayudes en algo revises este contenido de esta pregunta que esta arriba ya que tengo un problema con mi proyecto de laravel ya que no muestra los registros en mi componente vue (categoria.vue); hay códigos de ejemplos de los componente de mi proyecto y también hay una captura de pantalla de un mensaje de error que me sale si puedes darme una mano y ver como solucionar este error.

Comment: Estimado @gbianchi realice la instalación de axios en mi componente vue categoria.vue pero no envia la petición a traves de axios que recibe la petición por medio del archivo /routes/web.php que toma la ruta del controlador pero no llega la petición por alli y sale un mensaje de error si puedes me indicas ¿que podría hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: si seguro, podrias ingresar al chat abierto para esta pregunta?

Comment: si no tambien me encuentras en el [chat]

Comment: @gbianchi estimado no te entiendo a lo que te refieres al chat abierto ¿como ingreso?

Comment: presiona sobre el link del comentario para ingresar al chat

Comment: Estimado @fredyfx la idea lo que hace Axios es que envía peticiones del cliente http a traves de la url que por medio de su ruta ejecuta una función del controlador ejemplo en mi archivo /routes/web.php de mi proyecto laravel hay una linea de codigo de algunas que hay que dice Route::get('/categoria' , 'CategoriaController@index') que deberia ejecutar la función index de mi controlador me decia gbianchi que si hace la petición pero lo que hace falta mi direccion de backend no definido o esta mal ¿me puedes ser una guía en esto?

Comment: @gbianchi sobre esta pregunta que realice hace tiempo estimado ya esta solucionado en el código de axios puse lo siguiente axios.get('http://localhost/proyectolaravel/public/categoria'); y quedó solucionado alguien en esta página WEB me ayudo que fue de gran ayuda y me pudo solucionar y de allí en adelante todo esta bien. ¡Gracias! y te agradezco